# Loading dynamic content in JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have a problem loading dynamic content into a new JQuery dialog. When I click on the button nothing happens.

My code is below:

```
    <script  src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        //$('#dialog').dialog({ dialogClass: 'noTitleStuff' }); ---> CSS

         $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height:$(window).height() - 50,
                width:$(window).width() - 50,
                    show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 400,
                    },

                    hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 400
                    }
            });

            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                $( "#dialog").dialog({
                    open: function(event, ui) {
                           $('#content').load('http://www.google.com');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to define the open function in the initial dialog() setup:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: $(window).height() - 50,
    width: $(window).width() - 50,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 400,
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 400
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $('#content').load('http://www.google.com');
    }
});
```

And invoke it like so:

```
$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog('open');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGEK6/)

p.s.: you're using `$('#content')` but in the html you define `class="content"`

Answer (score 1):

Your content div has class, not an id. Below code will do the trick.

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                $( "#dialog").dialog({
                    open: function(event, ui) {
                           $('.content').load('http://www.google.com');
                    }
                }).dialog("open");
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is just load html inside that DOM and create dialog.

```
$('#content').load('http://www.google.com');

$( "#content" ).dialog( 'open' );
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the provided answers so far I would like to mention, that the provided examples are not working "out-of-the-box" because they are trying to load the Google-page. I stumbled upon this issue over the last half an hour until I read in the [JQuery documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

Just in case anybody else is having this issue and is wondering why the provided examples and JSFiddles are not working as expected.