# PHP and Bootstrap Modal Variables

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hopefully anybody can help me. 
I have an table with a while statement for my data. Now i want the data for each row displayed in an modal window.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Marke</th>
        <th>Modell</th>
        <th>Baujahr</th>
        <th>Aktion</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';
// Holen des Ergebis in die Variable $erg
while($erg_motor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_erg_motor))
#print_r($erg_motor);
{
    $body.='
    <tr>
        <td>'.$erg_motor['id'].'</td>
        <td><input name="motor_fabrikat" value="'.$erg_motor['motor_fabrikat'].'"></td>
        <td><input name="motor_modell" value="'.$erg_motor['motor_modell'].'"></td>
        <td><input name="motor_ez" value="'.$erg_motor['motor_ez'].'"></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</span></button></td>
    </tr>
    ';

}
$body.='
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Marke</th>
        <th>Modell</th>
        <th>Baujahr</th>
        <th>Aktion</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

and Code for my modal window

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Interne Vorgangsnummer: </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and now i want to display my unique key `$erg_motor['id']` in the modal body. Later i want to make an update on the data containing to `$erg_motor['id']`.

Comment: Considered doing it dynamically? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130419/loading-dynamic-content-in-jquery-dialog

Answer (score 0):

The while statement must be wrapped in 
The variables also must be wrapped in

Here is an example using foreach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>dynamic data</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Dynamic data</h2>
    <?php $arr = array('a','b','c','d'); ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($arr as $key => $val): ?>
            <li><?php echo $val; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Create a modal for each row of your table (bad)
2. Use JS/jQuery to get the id of the row clicked and populate your `$erg_motor['id']` into the modal.

An example for 2. would be:

Inside your loop, change tr to look like this:

```
<tr data-row-id='<?= $erg_motor['id'] ?>'>
```

Later using jQuery it's a piece of cake. First you need to handle the modal opening of your modal manually, so get rid of the extra attributes from your `<button>`. I'd recommend storing the row id temporarly on a hidden span inside the modal, it makes it easier to manage later.

```
$(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();

    $('tr button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var row_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-row-id');
        $('#myModal').find('.modal-body').find('span.row-id').val(row-id); // This span should be display:none;

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

After that I guess you'll have an edit form inside that modal, so just use jQuery to handle your POST edit and then change the row's data accordingly using `$('tr[data-row-id="THE-ID-FROM-THE-SPAN"]')`.

This is at least how I do it.

Comment: first of all. thank you. i am not sure if i am right.

Comment: Zeitstempel: 23.10.2014 12:49:39
Fehler: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
Quelldatei: 

Quelltext:
        var row-id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-row-id");

Comment: I changed `var row-id` to `var row_id` and it should work now, good luck.

Comment: Error: ReferenceError: row is not defined    -> the rest works fine. i have the id in my tr tag. but i seems to be that the variable was not sent to the script. do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

here is the code of the table:

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Marke</th>
                                        <th>Modell</th>
                                        <th>Baujahr</th>
                                        <th>Aktion</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>';
                                // Holen des Ergebis in die Variable $erg
                                while($erg_motor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_erg_motor))
                                #print_r($erg_motor);
                                {
                                    $body.='
                                    <tr data-row-id='.$erg_motor['id'].'>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['id'].'</td>
                                        <td><input name="motor_fabrikat" value="'.$erg_motor['motor_fabrikat'].'"></td>
                                        <td><input name="motor_modell" value="'.$erg_motor['motor_modell'].'"></td>
                                        <td><input name="motor_ez" value="'.$erg_motor['motor_ez'].'"></td>';
                                $body.='<td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</span></button></td>';


                                    $body.='</tr>';
                                }
                                $body.='
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>Marke</th>
                                        <th>Modell</th>
                                        <th>Baujahr</th>
                                        <th>Aktion</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
```